# How can numpy array indexing techniques can give different outputs for same input code?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random, array-indexing

```
#Code

import numpy as np    
np.random.seed(124)
x_2d = np.random.randint(1,50,(3,4,5))
print("I am getting wrong output => {}".format(x_2d[0][:][1]))
print("This is what I want => {} ".format(x_2d[0,:,1]))

# Code Ended

# Output for above code

I am getting wrong output => [42  1 21 29 15]
This is what I want => [29  1 22 49]
```

I am new to NumPy so I was just experimenting on numpy array selection techniques. I came to know that we can use square bracket method or comma method. But I encountered a problem. I am trying to extract column index 1 of array 0. But I am getting different outputs when I use both techniques. I have attached code snippets and outputs. Can anyone guide me where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `x_2d[0][:][1]`, first you get the first matrix `x_2d[0]`:

```
>>> first = x_2d[0]
>>> first
array([[15, 29, 18,  8,  3],
       [42,  1, 21, 29, 15],
       [22, 22, 28, 10, 31],
       [47, 49, 41, 10, 10]])
```

When you call `first[:]` you gonna receive exactly `first`, since you asking for all lines in `first`:

```
>>> second = first[:]
>>> second
array([[15, 29, 18,  8,  3],
       [42,  1, 21, 29, 15],
       [22, 22, 28, 10, 31],
       [47, 49, 41, 10, 10]])
```

So when you get `second[1]` you get the line of index 1

```
>>> third = second[1]
>>> third
array([42,  1, 21, 29, 15])
```

However when you ask for `x_2d[0,:,1]`, numpy interprets it as:

"From matrix 0 give me column 1 from the matrix composed by lines 0,1,2,3)"

So if you ask for `x_2d[1,0:2,3]` the result will be `[18, 2]`.

Conclusion: numpy does not interpret `x[0,:,1]` in the same way of `x[0][:][1]`. You can read more in the NumPy documentation [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).

Answer (score 2):

`x[0][:][1]` is equivalent to `x[0, 1, :]`, which is also equivalent to `x[0][1]`.

Reason being `[:]` alone basically means "copy this array", both in basic Python as well as Numpy. So you can read `x[0][:][1]` as "take the first element of array x, make a copy of it, then take the second element of the result."

`[:]` does not mean "skip a dimension".